# SQL multiple WHERE conditions for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create the following table:

| ID | Name | SalesDate | MaxNikeSales | MaxAdidasSales | SalesDifference (Nike - Adidas) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2022-01-01 | 94343 | 23453 | 70890 |
| 2 | John | 2022-01-02 | 23456 | 0 | 23456 |
| 3 | John | 2022-01-03 | 54678 | 0 | 54678 |
| 4 | John | 2022-01-04 | 12310 | 43345 | -31035 |
| 5 | John | 2022-01-05 | 0 | 94575 | -94575 |

I am trying to create the table using the WHERE clause, but am not sure how to get both brands to show as fields in the same table.

The data I am working with is structured as follows:

| Name | Brand | Sales | SalesDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Nike | 13344 | 2022-01-01 |
| John | Adidas | 23453 | 2022-01-01 |
| John | Nike | 94343 | 2022-01-01 |
| John | Nike | 23456 | 2022-01-02 |
| John | Nike | 54678 | 2022-01-03 |
| John | Nike | 23643 | 2022-01-03 |
| John | Nike | 12310 | 2022-01-04 |
| John | Adidas | 43345 | 2022-01-04 |
| John | Adidas | 94575 | 2022-01-05 |
| John | Adidas | 23451 | 2022-01-05 |

I would really appreciate any assistance on this.

Comment: Its not a where clause you want, its some form of pivot. Terminology wise, Table => Resultset, Field => Column. Also thats normally a problem you solve in your front end, not the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use max() with case clause to calculate what you need. Group the data by SalesDate and you have everything you need.

```
select row_number() over(order by SalesDate) as ID
       , max(Name)
       , SalesDate
       , max(case when Brand = 'Nike' then Sales else 0 end) MaxNikeSales
       , max(case when Brand = 'Adidas' then Sales else 0 end) MaxAdidasSales
       , max(case when Brand = 'Nike' then Sales else 0 end) - 
         max(case when Brand = 'Adidas' then Sales else 0 end) 
         as "SalesDifference (Nike - Adidas)"
from mytable
group by SalesDate
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d53f9682b8371351b3433ca79c0faff2)